# Which bottle will cool down faster (when quantity of water is same)?

Tags: experimental-physics, thermal-conductivity

if 2 water bottles(poly-pet) of two different quantities (1 and 2 liters) both are filled with same quantity of water (1 liter) i.e.., one bottle is fully filled and other half filled which one cools fast (i.e.. when i keep it in the fridge for specific period of time for an hour. )

Comment: Hint: consider the surface areas of the 2 bottles.

Answer (score 0):

This would mainly depend on the surface area of the water.

Water will only lose heat through its surface and, assuming that the thermal conductivity in both situations is constant, at equal mass the one with most surface area will cool down faster.

For this example, let's assume that the bigger bottle is wider and when filled halfway the height of the water is comparable to its width. The 1 liter bottle however, completely filled would be more long than wide. Thus the surface area of 1 liter bottle will be greater than for water in a 2 liter bottle and its surface area per volume will be greater. Consequently we can predict that in these conditions water filled in **1 liter bottle will cool down faster**.

Comment: $$ \rho c_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \left( k \nabla T \right) + \dot q_V $$ with a convective boundary condition $$ hA(T-T_ambient) $$

Comment: and if the surface area of both the bottles are same (considering only filled portion )